# Find next word after colon in regex

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I am getting a result as a return of a laravel console command like

> Some text as: 'Nerad'

Now i tried

> $regex = '/(?<=\bSome text as:\s)(?:[\w-]+)/is';
>
> preg_match_all( $regex, $d, $matches );

but its returning empty.
my guess is something is wrong with single quotes, for this i need to change the regex..
Any guess?

Comment: `$regex = "/(?<=\bSome text as:\s)'(?:[\w-]+)'/is";`

Answer (score 3):

Note that you get no match because the `'` before `Nerad` is not matched, nor checked with the lookbehind.

If you need to check the context, but avoid including it into the match, in PHP regex, it can be done with a `\K` match reset operator:

```
$regex = '/\bSome text as:\s*'\K[\w-]+/i';
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4AITss/1)

The output array structure will be cleaner than when using a capturing group and you may check for unknown width context (lookbehind patterns are fixed width in PHP PCRE regex):

```
$re = '/\bSome text as:\s*\'\K[\w-]+/i';
$str = "Some text as: 'Nerad'";
if (preg_match($re, $str, $match)) {
    echo $match[0];
} // => Nerad
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/7aLD7H)

Answer (score 1):

Just come from the back and capture the word in a group. The Group 1, will have the required string.

```
/:\s*'(\w+)'$/
```